# Manipulating UIImages for high resolution

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I am trying to build an app that allows a user to combine two UIImages, which I've got no problem by using Core Graphics. The user is able to pan and resize the photo in a view currently and I am combining the result of the views in an image context.

The size of the combined photo is small as it is just saving the visible portion of the image in the view it was in. To avoid shrinking the photo and then scaling it back up, do I have to provide a view for the user to alter the photo and then apply those changes (at the correct scale) to the full size photo?

I appreciate any help, if the above is confusing I can provide a code example, but just trying to see if I'm even heading down the right road or if there is a better way...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To avoid shrinking the photo and then scaling it back up, do I have to provide a view for the user to alter the photo and then apply those changes (at the correct scale) to the full size photo?

Yes, if you shrink the image to start with (to display to the user and to allow user manipulations) then clearly you must not throw away the original and scale the shrink image up again. You must keep the original and operate upon it. Otherwise, you lose lots of pixels forever.

However, why bother? The display will shrink *the way image is drawn* for you. If you show a large image in a UIImageView, using aspect fit mode, it is drawn within the image view and you have not had to do any shrinking yourself. Similarly if you set a CALayer's `contents` to a CGImage and the layer's `contentsGravity` is `kCAGravityResizeAspect`, the image is drawn within the bounds of the layer.

So do all your *operations* (drawing with CoreGraphics) at full size - this is the actual bitmap that is the target of your manipulations. Let display be performed for you.

(If you had several dozen images, yes, it would be a terrible strain to hold them all at full size in memory; it would probably crash the app. But one image should be fine. This, after all, is how the Photos app works.)

Comment: Ok, so to make sure I understand correctly, the way I have built this the user is actually transforming the ImageView, but I should have the user manipulating the actual image and letting the ImageView handle scaling the photo for the display? Thanks again, I would have upvoted but I don't have the reps yet.

Comment: You can't upvote but you can accept (checkmark) which is worth a lot more. :) But of course you are under no obligation to do that. - Your secondary question is hard to answer without seeing your code (i.e. exactly what you're doing). But I think that if, say, I were letting the user live-rotate an image by rotating an image view, I would let the user live-rotate the image view (which is merely a drawing transform) and _later_ I would apply that same rotation to the actual original image (by drawing it afresh with a transform).

Comment: Ok, yeah I think I understand... and I am doing exactly that, letting them live-scale, rotate and pan the imageview inside of another view by drawing transform. So the idea would be to record the transformation and apply to the actual (larger) original image once they commit? Thanks again, and I did accept the answer this time.

Comment: That is what I would do, so as not to have to keep redrawing the original image live throughout the gesture. In fact you could be really cool and store the original image and all applied transforms and thus allow everything to be undoable.